# 'Embedded' attribute type should not be @Embeddable class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an @Embeddable class:

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String region;

    private String city;

    private String district;

    private String street;

    private int house;
```

And I have another class where i'm trying to use it:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "db_order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_customer_id")
    private User customer;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzTdO.png)

But I can see an error 'Embedded' attribute type should not be 'Address'.
What can be a reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably IntelliJ doesn't know that the embeddable is part of your persistence unit. Have you listed the class in your persistence.xml?